# folder view option dont apply to all folders in mac os x

Tags: macos, finder

i set view option for a specific folder and set it to "use as default" but these setting wont apply to others folders.
how can i make a view option and apply that to all folders.

Comment: take a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/system-wide-finder-view-preferences